# Optimize SQL statement

Tags: sql

I have a requirement to update a column in table A if the count of records in table B grouped by 3 columns (matching between A and B) is less than 7. I have written below query, but it is running long. Please suggest any optimal query or tune this.

```
update /*+ parallel(A) */ A set A.col4=0
where exists
      (select 1 
       from B 
       where A.col1=B.col1 and A.col2=B.col2
          and A.col3=B.col3 
       group by col1,col2,col3
       having count(*) < 7)
```

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan on this? Do you have any indexes on these tables?

Comment: Are you using Oracle?

Comment: There's not information here, by far, to help you. At this point I'd suggest you look into query tuning in general. No useful and specific answer can be given.

Comment: Yes I am using oracle and I have checked the explain plan and I see the cost is very high.
To add some details, the columns which I have used in where clause are the primary key combination and my second table B will be having huge amount of data (It is a transaction table)

Comment: Below is the explain plan.
Query Plan                    Rows  Rowsource Time(s)
UPDATE STATEMENT   Cost = 831591   0
UPDATE  DFU         0
    FILTER           0 
TABLE ACCESS FULL DFU             210K   0
        FILTER                0
            HASH GROUP BY        1    0
   INDEX RANGE SCAN HIST_SELECT      8    0

Comment: Ignore the cost in the explain plan. It is used by the optimizer internally and can not be used to tell you if a plan is "fast" or slow".

Comment: There is also a logic flaw in your query: it wont touch the rows for which `COUNT(*) = 0` . And `0 < 7` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
MERGE INTO A 
USING (
SELECT col1, col2, col3
      FROM B
      GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 7
) b ON (A.col1 = b.col1 AND A.col2=b.col2 AND A.col3= b.col3)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET A.col4 = 0;
```

View it on SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dcdf1/17

Let me know if it worked or not!

Comment: per my knowledge the syntax is wrong. How can we have from clause just  after set clause in Update statement?

Comment: previously I wrote a code for SQL Server. Now I have modified it for Oracle. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Thanks Dipendu.. I have used this merge logic and prepared query per my requirement.. run time is 12 seconds with total count of rows in A is 200k+ and in B is 2 million+..

Comment: Welcome, I think it could be made even better by having INDEX on col1, col2 and col3 in the `table B`. Try it if you want to improve query performance even further.

Comment: The 3 columns I used in join condition are part of primary key on both the tables.

`MERGE INTO A 
USING (SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2,col3 
FROM (SELECT col1,col2,col3, 
COUNT ( 
1) 
OVER ( 
PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3, col4) 
cnt 
FROM B) 
WHERE cnt < 7) b 
ON ( A.col1=b.col1 
and A.col2=b.col2 
AND A.col3 = b.col3) 
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN 
UPDATE SET A.col5 = 0;`
Do I still need to explicitly add a hint to make the query use index?
I am expecting, query itself will go for the bast way

Comment: These columns form primary key of table A, and in table B they form foreign key referencing primary key of table A. Primary key is already clustered indexed. But  you may create index on these columns of table b. A single Index should be created  on combination of these 3 columns and not 3 separate indices for individual cols

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to create an index on `B`:  `B(col1, col2, col3)`.

The next attempt would be to switch this to a `join`:

```
update A
    set col4 = 0
    from (select col1, col2, col3
          from B
          group by col1, col2, col3
          having count(*) < 7
         ) B
    where A.col1 = B.col1 and A.col2 = B.col2
          and A.col3 = B.col3 ;
```